# Why my Android PieChart drawing behaves abnormally and I get duplicated slices on screen rotation?

Tags: java, android, pie-chart, screen-rotation

I need some help to fix this problem. I have a PieChart which is drawn in my android App using some data from a `MySQL` `db`. I am using an `AsyncTask` class implementation which loads the data from the server making an `HTTPPostRequest` and parsing the `JSON` response that is returned. The chart comes out fine and is drawn on the screen. The problem comes out when I rotate the device's screen: the Chart behaves abnormally and draws slices again... I don't know why it is doing that, but I read that if you rotate the screen all the methods of the `Activity` are called again (the `onCreate()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods). Maybe it's because of that??? But I am not sure... Here is how is look like:

[image]

Then when I rotate the device:

[image]

The data are duplicated! Why? What am I mistaking?

Here is all the code:

```
public class ComeHaInvestito extends Activity {

/**** PieChartBuilder ****/
/** Colors to be used for the pie slices. */
private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };
/** The main series that will include all the data. */
private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");
/** The main renderer for the main dataset. */
private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();
/** Edit text field for entering the slice value. */
//private EditText mValue;
/** The chart view that displays the data. */
private GraphicalView mChartView;

private int HowmanyTimes;
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedState) {
   super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedState);
   mSeries = (CategorySeries) savedState.getSerializable("current_series");
   mRenderer = (DefaultRenderer) savedState.getSerializable("current_renderer");
}

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putSerializable("current_series", mSeries);
    outState.putSerializable("current_renderer", mRenderer);
  }

/**** ComeHaInvestito ****/
// String which will store the values of the user 
String municipalityName;
String year;
String versedMoney;

// List<Item> ArrayList that will be used to store data from DB
List<Item> MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList;

private static final String TAG_COMUNE = "mun_name";
private static final String TAG_ANNO = "year";
private static final String TAG_VERSED_MONEY = "versed_money";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

// POST request information
private static final String URL_ANDROID_APP_LISTENER = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/androidApp/AndroidListener.php";

private ProgressDialog pDialog; 
// JSONParser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// JSON data retrieving information
private static final String JSON_STATISTICS_INFOS_LABEL = "statistics_infos";   
private static final String JSON_MASTER_LABEL = "master";
private static final String JSON_DETAIL_LABEL = "detail";
private static final String JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL = "name";
private static final String JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_VALUE_LABEL ="value";

// statistics info JSON Array which will contain the Master and Detail data that will come from the POST request
JSONArray statisticsInfo = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_come_ha_investito);
    Log.d("OnCREATE", "CREO L'ACTIVITY");
    // recovering data from previous actitity
    Intent iMieiDati = getIntent();
    this.municipalityName = iMieiDati.getStringExtra(TAG_COMUNE);
    this.year = iMieiDati.getStringExtra(TAG_ANNO);
    this.versedMoney = iMieiDati.getStringExtra(TAG_VERSED_MONEY);

    // instantiating the needed data structure
    MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    mRenderer.setStartAngle(270);
    mRenderer.setDisplayValues(true);

    new LoadAllMunicipalitiesInvestmentStatisticsThread().execute();

    //mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pie_chart_builder2, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (mChartView == null) {
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
      mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer);
      mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
      mChartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
          if (seriesSelection == null) {
            Toast.makeText(ComeHaInvestito.this, "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          } 
          else {
            for (int i = 0; i < mSeries.getItemCount(); i++) {
              mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());
            }
           // mChartView.repaint();

            Toast.makeText(
                ComeHaInvestito.this,
                "Chart data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " selected"
                    + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          }
        }
      });
      layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    } 
    else {
      //mChartView.repaint();
    }
  }


  private void initChart() {
        int i=0;
        double value=0;
        for (Item item : MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList) {
            if (i == 4) {
                break;
            }
            Log.d("Ciclo ", "NUMERO " + i);
            if (item.getViewType() == EntryType.MASTER.ordinal()) { 
                MasterWithValue master = (MasterWithValue) item;
                Log.d("MASTER NAME", master.getMasterName());
                Log.d("MASTER VALUE", master.getMasterValue());
                try {
                    value = Double.parseDouble(master.getMasterValue());
                } 
                catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // value is not a decimal
                }
                mSeries.add(master.getMasterName(), value);
                SimpleSeriesRenderer renderer = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                renderer.setColor(COLORS[i%4]);
                i++;
                mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
                Log.d("mSeries", mSeries.toString());
            }
        }
  }

/**** Background Thread ****/
public class LoadAllMunicipalitiesInvestmentStatisticsThread extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ComeHaInvestito.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();         
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        Log.d("ilMioComune", "Caricamento Statistiche Investimenti");
        // building the HTTP POST request
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_COMUNE, municipalityName));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ANNO, year));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_VERSED_MONEY, versedMoney));
        Log.d("params", params.toString());
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_ANDROID_APP_LISTENER, "POST", params);

        Log.d("JSON POST statistics investments", json.toString());
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {

                statisticsInfo = json.getJSONArray(JSON_STATISTICS_INFOS_LABEL);

                // foreach Statistics Master Entry
                for (int i = 0; i<statisticsInfo.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject JSONstatisticsInfo = statisticsInfo.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject JSONmasterEntry = JSONstatisticsInfo.getJSONObject(JSON_MASTER_LABEL);

                    String masterEntryName = JSONmasterEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL);
                    String masterEntryValue = JSONmasterEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_VALUE_LABEL);
                    MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList.add(new MasterWithValue(masterEntryName, masterEntryValue));                      

                    JSONArray JSONdetails = JSONmasterEntry.getJSONArray(JSON_DETAIL_LABEL);
                    for (int j = 0; j<JSONdetails.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject JSONdetailEntry = JSONdetails.getJSONObject(j);

                        String detailEntryName = JSONdetailEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_NAME_LABEL);
                        String detailEntryValue = JSONdetailEntry.getString(JSON_MASTER_DETAIL_VALUE_LABEL);

                        MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList.add(new Detail(detailEntryName, detailEntryValue));
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // no statistics infos associated to the selected municipality were found
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String MasterAndDetails = MasterAndDetailstatisticsInfoList.toString();
                Log.d("List", MasterAndDetails);

                // Creating the pie chart using the data recovered from the DB
                 initChart();
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Thanks for the attention! Hope fore some help!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, etc. get called whenever you rotate. Because of this, you are calling `new LoadAllMunicipalitiesInvestmentStatisticsThread().execute();` twice essentially.

You should move your data initialization logic to one place, and either load that data from the savedInstanceState, or call the initialize logic if the savedInstanceState returns null.

For example:

*change declaration to*

`private CategorySeries mSeries = null;`

*in `onCreate()`*

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
  mSeries = (CategorySeries) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("current_series");

if(mSeries == null)
{
  mSeries = new CategorySeries("");
  new LoadAllMunicipalitiesInvestmentStatisticsThread().execute(); //this line can be substituted for a new init method, which would contain the thread.execute
}
```

Comment: i have added those lines in my onCreate() method but I get a Java Null Pointer Exception, at the line -- mSeries = (CategorySeries) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("current_series"); -- I have tried to put those lines before and after the --super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); -- call at the start of the onCreate() method. What should I do know?

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: check if savedInstanceState is null or not, it will be null if onCreate is not being called from a saved instance (ie the first time the activity is launched). edited my answer.